# .Net 6 ClickOnce publish option "produce single file" results in missing resource files, although manually included

Tags: winforms, deployment, clickonce, .net-6.0

.Net6 WinForms application using language resource files (not belonging to a form, just to store texts accessed via ResourceManager). Build action "embedded resource"/"Do not copy".

In VS publish GUI, application files manually changed from "included (Auto)" to "included", changing download group to "required" and Hash to "include".

**ISSUE: when publish option "Produce single file" is selected, the language resource files are not included in the publish output dir, resulting in installation error**

- Downloading https://xxx/xxx_5_0_0_31/fr/Cat.resources.dll.deploy did not succeed.
  + The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

When the "produce single file" is deselected, the language resource files are available in publish dir and installation is working. However you then have hundreds of files in the publish dir.

Is there any work around for this issue?

Comment: Question needs to explain some context, it is like these points just 'are'.

Comment: I wonder if someone can reproduce or confirm this behavior, and if so, can it be considered a bug and how to report it then.